# Vuetify open drop down menu center to button

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a drop down menu with two rows of v-list items as shown below.

```
<v-menu
  class="dropdown"
  open-on-hover
  offset-y
>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-btn
      class="rounded-xl green darken-3 text-capitalize elevation-2 ml-2"
      dark
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"
    >
      The Society
    </v-btn>
  </template>

  <v-list class="pa-6">
    <v-list-item>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
          <h1 class="display-1 orange--text">Important Info</h1>
          <v-divider class="ma-3"></v-divider>
          <v-list-item><v-btn class="ml-n6" text>Our Constitution <v-icon class="ml-3">mdi-security</v-icon></v-btn></v-list-item>
          <v-list-item class="body-2" to="/">Lorem ipsum.</v-list-item>
          <v-list-item class="body-2" to="/">Lorem ipsum.</v-list-item>
          <v-list-item class="body-2" to="/">Lorem ipsum.</v-list-item>
          <v-list-item class="body-2" to="/">Lorem ipsum.</v-list-item>
        </v-col>
        <v-divider vertical></v-divider>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
          <h1 class="display-1 orange--text">Important Info</h1>
          <v-divider class="ma-3"></v-divider>
          <v-list-item class="body-2" to="/">Lorem ipsum.</v-list-item>
          <v-list-item class="body-2" to="/">Lorem ipsum.</v-list-item>
          <v-list-item class="body-2" to="/">Lorem ipsum.</v-list-item>
          <v-list-item class="body-2" to="/">Lorem ipsum.</v-list-item>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

I need this menu to open centre to the **The Society** button and not pushing to the right as it does presently. So the middle line of the drop down should be centre to the **The Society** button.

[image: Menu Offset]

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that there is a **nudge-left** api available for v-menu's. Thank you Vuetify for this amazing framework!

My Code

```
<v-menu
      open-on-hover
      nudge-left="220"
      nudge-bottom="50"
    >
```

This looks like it solved my issue.

Find the API here
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props